# Blue Prism: Cannot Iterate through JSON items withing injected JS script

Tags: javascript, json, blueprism

So I am trying to iterate through JSON items via injected script. And BP is throwing me a syntax error that it is incapable of compiling my code.

code:

```
function fillInputs(json){ 
    alert(json[0].Email); 
}
```

through Invoke I am giving [JSON] variable that has a well structured JSON object which I created with help of Utility - JSON and it is working fine on test websites. But BP will not initialize specifically this part / alert(json[0].Email); / and is throwing a standard error which usually means syntax errors.

Could someone tell me if there is a better way to iterate through JSON objects with Blue Prism injected Javascript code and if I am choosing a harsh way to do it?

Comment: Please show us the resulted JSON.
I would guess you get an object based one.

Comment: JSON:

[{"First Name":"John","Last Name ":"Smith","Company Name":"IT Solutions","Role in Company":"Analyst","Address":"98 North Road","Email":"jsmith@itsolutions.co.uk","Phone Number":"40716543298"},
{"First Name":"Jane","Last Name ":"Dorsey","Company Name":"MediCare","Role in Company":"Medical Engineer","Address":"11 Crown Street","Email":"jdorsey@mc.com","Phone Number":"40791345621"}]

Comment: Please note that if you do not have experience with Blue Prism you might not know what am I dealing with, because testing on any other environment will give me right answer as I expect it. Without any syntax error.

Also I posted an unformatted  version of JSON ... Before pushing it to the function I also cover all space like First" "Name with dashes "_".

Comment: Javascript is javascript, no matter what framework you use on top of that.
It would be helpful to get the exact error you are getting and a minimum replication of the issue.
I would also suggest to move the JSON example to your question and not as a comment, so other people could easily see it.
P.S Welcome to SO, Where we all try to join our efforts to help each other.
disrespecting and/or devaluing other members, would not get you far.
Good luck with your issue.

Comment: Dear Sir,

I did not want to sound or be rude. This is probably European way of communication. But as I already said that Blue prism is neglecting any java script code with slightest error in it. It is very strange for me, because I was injecting JS code with greese monkey and tamper monkey and never faced such issues.

Comment: Please add the exact error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

This is easily accomplished using the built-in Internet Explorer browser automation features provided out of the box in Blue Prism.

For organization, place your custom Javascript in a data item of type text on your action page:

[image]

Then use a Navigate stage to insert the fragment and invoke it:

[image]

[image]

[image]

With your current snippet, you'll get a nice alert window in Internet Explorer:

[image]

A good way to retrieve this data using Blue Prism would be to use the Javascript snippet you insert to create a hidden input element, the value of which is set a string representation of the JSON data you're attempting to exfiltrate.

You can then create a manual Application Modeler entry based off of an existing one to target this hidden element, and then use a Read stage to copy the data into a Data Item within Blue Prism. Further, you can use the bundled JSON object (or write your own as a wrapper around a better VB/C# library) to extract and manipulate the data within as you wish.

Comment: I just wanted to clarify this tiny bit. Your main action Item is called Insert and Invoke, But in screenshots you did only two inserts, is that a miss type or was there a change done after screenshot was taken?

Comment: @JefimKundzinovic I've found the "invoke" functionality to be a bit flaky, I just use the "Insert Javascript Snippet" to invoke my custom functionality (especially those where we have to pass arguments). Not sure why that is, but this has worked for me across multiple implementations and I've just stuck with it since.